# Enterpad Device do a Double Click to Execute a Autohotkey Script

Tags: user-interface, scripting, autohotkey

I am using a Cedeq **[Enterpad Device](https://cedeq.com/)** and i want to do Double Click to Execute a Autohotkey Script.

With a Fysical Enterpad device (Cedeq): 
you can Stay always your Right hand on the Mouse Device and you can execute with the Left Hand (finger) in one Button Click do a simple or complex Computer Movement with the help of Autohotkey Commanding Scripts.

[image]

But i want to do this:

001-copy1or2 002-paste1or2 003-cut1or2

And It must can do this:

- Double Click Button 001 to execute Ahk command copy1.
- and if i Hold any kind of button on the Enterpad device and Click the
  Button 001 it must execute Ahk command copy2.

This is the Ahk Code that i can use, for one Button Click.

```
;-----------------------------------------------------------001------
001:
Sentinput ^c ;Copy1 
Return
;-----------------------------------------------------------002------
002:
Sentinput ^v ;Paste1 
Return
;-----------------------------------------------------------003------
003:
Sentinput ^x ;Cut1 
Return
;--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]